Return typed object from json file
In nextjs, I'm using this example to load translations and return them into the component
import "server-only";
import i18nConfig from "../../i18n-config";

const dictionaries = {
  en: () =>
    import("../../dictionaries/en.json").then((module) => module.default),
  hr: () =>
    import("../../dictionaries/hr.json").then((module) => module.default),
};

type TDictionary = (typeof dictionaries)["en"];

export const getDictionary = async (locale: string): Promise<TDictionary> =>
  dictionaries[
    i18nConfig.locales.includes(locale) ? locale : i18nConfig.defaultLocale
  ]();

export default async function Navbar ( props: ILangParams ) {
  const dict = await getDictionary(props.params.lang); 

  return (
    <nav className={styles.navbar}>
      <Link href="/" className={styles.linkLogo}>
        <Image
          priority
          src={logo}
          alt={dict.navbar.links.home}
          className={styles.logo}
        />
    </nav>
  );
}

If I don't type getDictionary to return Promise<TDictionary>, it returns as Promise<any>.
With Promise<TDictionary>, it returns
const dict: () => Promise<{
    navbar: {
        links: {
            logoAlt: string;
            escapeGames: string;
            becomeAPartner: string;
            bookDemo: string;
        };
    };
}>

This seems wrong as I cannot use dict.navbar.links.home to get the translated string.
How do I properly type this?
the structure is the same for all translations, so I only have to cast it as one of those files ((typeof dictionaries)["en"])

...you are confusing compile time with runtime. Typescript, and other static analysis tooling, does not run your code to do type-checking. That's why it's called "static" analysis. It logically cannot know about the shape of data in a JSON file that gets read at runtime: you could edit the file between the time the compiler checks the types and the time the file is dynamically read at runtime. Either store the data in Typescript files, or do runtime checks to validate the shape of the parsed JSON, or YOLO an any or a type cast and accept the fact that you might get a runtime error.

Does this answer your question? Typing dynamic import

I am pretty sure that the file in question is not dynamic. The file is in my project and it never changes. Once any of those files are loaded, I only need to type them as "en" json file, since the structure is the same in other files. The ReturnType<(typeof dictionaries)["fr"]> from one of those answers below solved the issue.

You are dynamically importing that file at runtime using the import function. That makes it opaque to the compiler. You as the human programmer might know that file never changes, but there's no way for the compiler to prove it at compile-time, any more than it can prove the type of something that you fetch over the network and then run JSON.parse on. If you are confident it won't change just use a type cast like in the answer you accepted. Or write some runtime validation logic, your call.

I have a piece of code that works, it's pretty close to the one you wrote.
export type Lang = "fr" | "en" | "zh"

const dictionaries = {
    fr: () => import('./dictionaries/fr.json').then((module) => module.default),
    en: () => import('./dictionaries/en.json').then((module) => module.default),
    zh: () => import('./dictionaries/zh.json').then((module) => module.default),
}

type TDictionary = ReturnType<(typeof dictionaries)["fr"]>; // has to be the return type 

// The type of lang has to be union type
// otherwise you will get the error "Element implicitly has an 'any' type"
export default async function getDictionary(lang: Lang): Promise<TDictionary> {
    return dictionaries[lang]();
}


This does not answer the question. You are guessing, answers are for definitive... well, answers to the question. In this case OPs problem is that Typescript cannot verify at compile-time the data from a dynamic import at runtime, it has nothing to do with the shape of the data. See my comments on the question and the linked duplicate.

Thanks! It works, the ReturnType was the answer.

I have removed my downvote post-edit. Please do note though that this is still effectively a type cast and not type safe, for the reason stated in my original comment.

Instead of using the below portion:
export const getDictionary = async (locale: string): Promise<TDictionary> =>
  dictionaries[
    i18nConfig.locales.includes(locale) ? locale : i18nConfig.defaultLocale
  ]();

you can use below given code and your problem will be solved:
// @ts-ignore
export const getDictionary = async (locale: Locale) => dictionaries[locale]();

Also, try to destructure the translation objects when you call the getDictionary function:
const {home, navbar,...} = await getDictionary(props.params.lang); 

it will make your work a bit simpler.

let me know if you need any further assistance.. thanks
